# Encoding a large result set into a JSON

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I'm trying to encode a result set of more than 1 million rows x 50 columns, into a json, i'm creating a histogram with D3, and the queries works fine for small results like 50k or 100k rows, but when i started to use a bigger DB i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

is there a solution that don't involve just giving all the memory to the process? (also, i can't limit the query, because for the histogram i need all the data)

Comment: not directly. json_encode only accepts a single monolithic data_structure for encoding. you can't feed in data piece-wise. that means you'd need probably 2x the ram that your structure requires (original + encoded string). for a huge data set, you might have to bite the bullet and encoding piece-wise manually, which means you're responsible for generating syntactically valid json yourself.

Comment: @MarcB Holy... well, i guess i will look at it, thanks for your fast reply...

Comment: How much RAM did you have?  Increase the memory limit.

Comment: @AbraCadaver 1073741824 looks like a Gig to me

Comment: RiggsFolly indeed , it is 1GB, and @AbraCadaver as i said i can't just be giving all the memory to the process as the data will be increasing, so i was looking for another type of solution.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. If you're simply encoding 2D data like database results why not use a simpler, streamable format like CSV?

Comment: @RiggsFolly:  No 1GB is what PHP is allowed to use.  There may be 8GB available, who knows.

Comment: Have you looked at [SPLFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) Its got some limitations that may mean its no use to you but it does not suffer from the standard PHP Array mechanism of allocating lots more memory than it actually needs. I did a quick test and `json_encode()` will process a SPLFixedArray into a JSON String

Comment: thanks @Sammitch and Riggs, i'm gonna look both of your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: encode each row.. and append... also, might looks at generators:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php